# I don't know why I am getting undefined. How can I make this work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am searching for a user, when I find it I want to set it to config state. Now, when I search among children arrays I got a type error saying "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined". Why is it like this? How can I solve it?
I can set the config state if there is no username. Also, if I put a console.log or change something and save, I notice that the page reloads and my searched object is set even if previously it was said that Cannot read property 'children' of undefined.
here the code.

```
  const [config, setConfig] = useState({});



 const makeTree = (users) => {
    let tree = {children:[]};
    for (const person of users) {
      if (!person.report) {
        tree = { ...person, ...tree };
      } else {
        if (tree.name === person.report) {
          tree.children.push(person);
        } else {
          tree.children?.forEach(child => {
            if (child.name === person.report) {
              child.children = [];
              child.children.push(person)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }

    return tree;
  };

  const searchInChildren = (children, name) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<children.length; i++) {
      
      if (children[i]?.name === name) {
        setConfig(getConfig(children[i]));
      }
       else if (children[i] && children[i].children && children[i].children.length > 0) {
        searchInChildren(children[i].children, name)
      } else {
        console.log("not found!")
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/schema")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (username) {
          const treeObj = {...makeTree(data)};
          console.log("tree", treeObj);
          const regex = new RegExp(username, "gi");
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (regex.test(data[i].name)) {
              if (treeObj.name === data[i].name) {
                setConfig(getConfig(treeObj))
              } else {
                console.log("treeObj.children",treeObj.children, data[i] );
                searchInChildren(treeObj.children, data[i].name)
              }

            }
          }
        } else {
          setConfig(getConfig(makeTree(data)));
        }
        if(deleteSearch){
            console.log("hi",deleteSearch);
            setConfig(getConfig(makeTree(data)));
        }
      });
  }, [username, deleteSearch])
```

;

Comment: I don't use react, but are you sure you are using `?` properly here `tree.children?.forEach` and here `children[i]?.name === name`

Comment: Check the error happen in which line of `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined` and it will be more efficient to find the problem.

Comment: even if I delete "?" I get the same problem. If I check the error I get some info related with the chart I send the config state. How ever when I don't search it doesn't give problem, so I think it is wrong with the initial search state. Also, after I write console.log in the code, I see that the error disapear and I get what I want.

Comment: @cri_pava the `?` checks if children' value is undefined or not, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining